# OpenCL: better to use macros or functions?

Tags: opencl

In OpenCL, which is C-99, we have two options for creating something function-like:

- macros
- functions
- [edit: well, or use a templating language, new option 3 :-) ]

I heard somewhere (can't find any official reference to this anywhere, just saw it in a comment somewhere on stackoverflow, once), that functions are almost always inlined in practice, and that therefore using functions is ok performance-wise?

But macros are basically guaranteed to be inlined, by the nature of macros.  But susceptible to bugs, eg if dont add parentheses around everything, and not typesafe.

In practice, what works well?  What is most standard?  What is likely to be most portable?

I suppose my requirements are some combination of:

- as fast as possible
- as little register pressure as possible
- when used with compile-time constants, should ideally be guaranteed to be optimized-away to another constant
- easy to maintain...
- standard, not too weird, since I'm looking at using this for an opensource project, that I hope other people will contribute to

Comment: Functions are inlined on GPUs, but on CPU implementations of OpenCL this might not be the case.

Comment: Guaranteed inlined? And does this mean that if I pass #define constants into a function, that has no non-#define inputs, that the compiler will process this at compiler time, and replace the function call with a single constant?

Comment: Not guaranteed, but from my experience the GPU implementations inline functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But macros are basically guaranteed to be inlined, by the nature of macros.

On GPU at least, the OpenCL compilers aggressively inlines pretty much everything, with the exception of recursive functions (OpenCL 2.0). This is both for hardware constraints and performance reasons.

While this is indeed implementation dependent, I have yet to see a GPU binary that is not aggressively inlined. I do not work much with CPU OpenCL but I believe the optimizer strategy may be similar, although the hardware constraints are not the same.

But as far as the standard is concerned, there are no guarantees.

Let's go through your requirements:

> - as fast as possible
> - as little register pressure as possible
> - when used with compile-time constants, should ideally be guaranteed to be optimized-away to another constant

Inline functions are as fast as macros, do not use more registers, and will be optimized away when possible.

> - easy to maintain...

Functions are **much** easier to maintain that macros. They are type safe, they can be refactored easily, etc, the list goes on forever.

> - standard, not too weird, since I'm looking at using this for an opensource project, that I hope other people will contribute to

I believe that is very subjective. I personally hate macros with a passion and avoid them like the plague. But I know some very successful projects that use them extensively (for example [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute)). It's up to you.

Comment: Cool. I'd much prefer to use functions, if I have the reassurance they will be inlined, aggressively optimized away, and what you are saying is very reassuring.  Are there any official sources/statements to back this up?  Is it the case for all platforms, or just for eg nvidia?